# PHP Using $i to count

Tags: php, variables

Hello I want to add a number to the variable each time it loops so that I can pick up that variable later.

```
<?php
$i=1;
while($i<=5)
  {
  $myinfo.$i = "This is the text I can change";
  $i++;
  }
?>

<?php echo $myinfo1 ?>
<?php echo $myinfo2 ?>
<?php echo $myinfo3 ?>
<?php echo $myinfo4 ?>
<?php echo $myinfo5 ?>
```

I can not include the "myinfo1" in the loop because I need to add this to a table a little way down the page.

I am sorry if this is not clear but I do not know the right name for what I am trying to do.

If anyone can help that will be great.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
<?php
$i=1;
while($i<=5)
  {
  ${'myinfo'.$i} = "This is the text I can change";
  $i++;
  }
?>

<?php echo $myinfo1 ?>
<?php echo $myinfo2 ?>
<?php echo $myinfo3 ?>
<?php echo $myinfo4 ?>
<?php echo $myinfo5 ?>
```

(but using arrays is a better solution !)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using an array instead of named variables? By changing to this kind of architecture, you gain the ability to add more items without having to change your code (add more lines of `$myInfoX`). As you develop, this method will also be easier to read and add to than your current code.

For example,

```
  $myInfo = array(); 

  for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) 
  {
     $myInfo[] = "This is the text I can change";
  }
```

This will result in an array with a numbered index that you can recall like this:

```
<?php echo $myInfo[2]; //returns "This is the text I can change" ?>
```

You can also use the array in a loop like this:

```
<?php 
     for($info in $myInfo)
     {
         echo $info; 
     }
 ?>
```

That will print each element in the array in turn.

Answer (score 0):

A for-loop would simplify things.

Try this:

```
$myinfo1 = "String of text 1";
$myinfo2 = "String of text 2";
$myinfo3 = "String of text 3";
$myinfo4 = "String of text 4";
$myinfo5 = "String of text 5";

for ($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++){
     echo $myinfo . $i "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just to make you sure about this

```
 <?php echo $myinfo1  ;?>
                      ^--------------   you are missing this
```

this is should be your code like that

```
 <?php
$myinfo1 = "This is the text I can change"; 
$myinfo2 = "This is the text I can change";   
$myinfo3 = "This is the text I can change";   
$myinfo4 = "This is the text I can change";   
$myinfo5 = "This is the text I can change";        

 for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) 
 {
echo  $myinfo.$i ;

 }
 ?>
```